# Contact Form 7 Shortcode not recognized inside another shortcode

Tags: posts, shortcode

I've created a code snippet with its shortcode to hide part of the post content for non-logged users:
[private]
...
[/private]

works great but when I try to put another shortcode (contact form 7) inside its not recognized. What could be the problem?

This is my code snippet:

```
function bp_contenido_privado( $atts, $content = null ) {
   if ( is_user_logged_in() )
   return $content;
   return '<p style="font-weight:bold;padding-top:10px;">Este contenido esta reservado para los usuarios registrados. Registrate <a href="'.wp_registration_url().'">aquí</a> o <a href="'.wp_login_url(get_permalink()).'">inicia la sesión</a> para poder verlo..</p>';
}
```

and this is the post content:

```
[privado]
<h4>Por favor llene los datos solicitados. Los formatos aceptados para subir archivos son pdf y jpg con un tamaño máximo de 2mb.</h4>
[contact-form-7 id="3584" title="Formulario de Inscripción"]
[/privado]
```

Comment: Can you please post your shortcode function? Also, post how you are trying to pass the shortcode.

Comment: already updated the question

Comment: I'm assuming you are seeing the shortcode code and not what you are expecting. What you can do to test is wrap `$content` in `return do_shortcode( $content );` As a side note, I would strongly recommend wrapping your `if` statement in `{}`. Much easier to read.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: I'll post as an answer for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the entire `return` output in a `do_shortcode()`. That will render the shortcode as well as output the regular content.

```
function bp_contenido_privado( $atts, $content = null ) {
   if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      return do_shortcode( $content );
   }
   return '<p style="font-weight:bold;padding-top:10px;">Este contenido esta reservado para los usuarios registrados. Registrate <a href="'.wp_registration_url().'">aquí</a> o <a href="'.wp_login_url(get_permalink()).'">inicia la sesión</a> para poder verlo..</p>';
}
```